# correct way of giving domain in connection string

Tags: soapui

I am trying to connect database using soapui and in JDBC request I am passing connection string in the format:

`jdbc:sqlserver://<server>:<port>/<databaseName>;domain<yourdomain>;trusted_connection=yes;user=<user>;password=<password>`

But I am getting error of login failed for the credentials that I am providing in string. I know My credentials are correct but seems there is some problem in format. I know my connection string is correct because I am able to connect on IDE but not on SoapUI.

I have checked by passing as domain\username also but it did not work for me.
Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: what exactly error did you receive? Check also the `error log` tab of SOAPUI for more details `:)`

Comment: Also: where are you doing this? In a JDBC test step, or from a Groovy script?

Comment: @Siking I'm not sure but I suppose that is using `JDBC Test step` since in the question the OP says `JDBC request` `:)`

Comment: @albciff I think a JDBC test step requires username:password to be passed separately, not in the connect string. But now we're speculating about the OP's problem, aka: game of 21 questions. :(

Comment: @Siking nops `:)` you can pass username and password in the connection string using `JDBC Test Request`. I can connect to oracle DB on my tests using an specifying both on connection string (an also all are properties from the project): `jdbc:oracle:thin:${#Project#NT_DB_user}/${#Project#NT_DB_password}@${#Project#NT_DB_host}:${#Project#NT_DB_port}:${#Project#NT_DB_sname}`... sorry I like to play even to the 21 questions boring game `:)`

Comment: @albciff : error which i am getting is login failed for the 'user'.I hope I am giving the domain name in the correct format.and I am not using PRO so giving username password in string only.there is nothing in error log.

Comment: @albciff : I have checked server's security settings also and server authentication is set to both, so that should not be the case here. server is on different machine and I am accessing it using remote desktop.

Comment: tried with jtds driver also but it did not work for me :(

Comment: another error which I am getting while changing driver to 'jtds' is -ERROR:java.sql.SQLException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
For this I have checked server authentication setting and its set to both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

folks, my login credentials worked fine somehow but later I faced window authentication fails issue so I have tried using useNTLMv2=true in my string and it did work for me. Problem was with window authentication. thanks anyway :)